# Where is the web app API documentation?

Tags: unity, webapps, documentation

The API reference for Unity Web Apps seems to have disappeared. There's a link from http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/platform/api/12-10/ to "Web developer documentation", but it's broken. Does this documentation still exist somewhere?

Comment: The links should be fixed now.

Comment: at least it's fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit more asking around I found that [it is still supported, and the links are now fixed.](http://test.ubuntu-discourse.org/t/unity-web-app-integration-still-relevant/879/3)